# Desktop audio coming through microphone

Tags: audio, microphone, headphones

On my windows 10 pc I have had an issue in multiple programs such as discord where my audio will also pick up desktop or audio from other tabs, the issue seems to be with the audio device drivers from what I have looked up, I tried to uninstall the Realtek drivers as that seems to be an issue but restarting reinstalls them as it seems those are the default drivers.

Both the microphone is on a headset, the headphones and mic connect to a 1.5 mm jack on the front of the pc.

I've tried messing with almost every setting as far as I can tell to no avail and hoping that someone may have had this issue before and might know a fix. If any more info is needed let me know and I will be happy to send, Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the sound levels for specific open applications? Settings > System > Sound > Advanced Sounds Options.  There you can mute or reduce the sound output of other applications that may be interfering with the applications you want to use with sound.

Comment: I have and it sorta works but it still picks it up, just as a lesser noise than before (the threshold which it picks up my voice is still passed if the game or vider has a loud noise like an explosion or a high pitched voice)

Comment: Does this also happen with other headsets/microphones? What happens when you turn off audio output to your headset and have it output to your speakers instead?

Comment: I don't have speakers on my pc, turning my headset input off causes it to not be heard, but the issue persists across other headsets as far as I can tell